# Apply is throwing an error of Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In the jstree plugin there is a function like this :

```
this.check_node = function (obj, e) {
    if(this.settings.checkbox.tie_selection) { return this.select_node(obj, false, true, e); }
    // Removed code for readability
};
```

So for the `check_node` I have to pass a list of arguments, the list of arguments I have to pass are in an array, so I do as following :

```
scope.jstree(true).check_node(...scope.args['check_node']);
```

Where `scope.args['check_node']` contains the list of args I want to pass to `check_node`, doing this with spread operator won't raise any error, but for a reason I can't work with ES6 syntax and I'm stuck with ES5, so I had to use `apply` instead as following :

```
scope.jstree(true).check_node.apply(null, scope.args['check_node']);
```

But this will throw the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of null
```

which is in this line :

```
if(this.settings.checkbox.tie_selection)
```

Why apply in this case is throwing the error and the spread oprator is not ? and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Just FWIW, `...` isn't an operator (and can't be, an operator has to have a single result value). It's just syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're explicitly saying "Make `this` during the function call `null`" by passing `null` as the first argument.

You need to pass the value you want to be `this` as the first argument.

I'm not familiar with your library, but this will do it:

```
var obj = scope.jstree(true);
obj.check_node.apply(obj, scope.args['check_node']);
```

If `jstree` returns `scope`, though, you can avoid the variable:

```
scope.jstree(true).check_node.apply(scope, scope.args['check_node']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your ES5 code you are explicitly passing `null` for `thisArg`, so `this` is `null` inside the called function. No surprise here.

The spread operator simply expands the array in a way such as if you would have passed its values on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing this of check_node with null.The first parameter that apply takes is the object/context which should act as this for the function that you have invoked.